# Scrollbar visible on large screens?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I created a web application where I have a section that is scrollable. When I view the page on my MacBook Screen the scrollbar looks as expected. It only appears on scrolling and doesn't have the border around it. However when I use my external Monitor with my MacBook the scrollbar is always visible and has this weird border around it.

[MacBook Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpNRG.png)

[External Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBhQI.png)

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Could you show us some code for better context?

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Hope It Works!

Comment: It is already set to overflow-y: auto unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide scroll bar for larger screens (still scrollable)

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */

.example::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */

.example {
-ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```